# In Python, a function will be passed to an object as a member. Is there any place-holder in the function that refers to the future object?

Tags: python

I've come to a weird situation with py2.7. The code is like:

```
from random import randint

class A:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.f = func

    def callfunc(self):
        self.f()

    def odd(self):
        a = randint(1, 42)
        return a % 2

def foo():
    # Is there any place-holder here that refers to an object of A?
    # for example a place-holder named X
    if X.odd():
        # ...
    else:
        # ...

a = A(foo)
a.callfunc()
```

I've tried to pass it as a parameter to `foo`:

```
def foo(X):
    # ...
```

and in `A`:

```
def callfunc(self):
    self.f(self)
```

and it seems to work. I wonder if such place-holder X exists without being passed as a parameter or if there is any method that can dynamically retrieve the object in the scope of `foo`.

Comment: Yes, `foo(X)` and `f(self)` is basically the answer. It's unclear what you mean by "placeholder".

Comment: @deceze a variable like `self`. I just don't know how to describe it properly in English.

Comment: Functions are just objects. And so are instances of a class. All variables are 'placeholders' in that they can be a reference to anything. But you can't magically retrieve a reference here, just explicitly pass it in.

Comment: `foo` needs an object as argument that has an `odd` method. So `foo` needs an argument. And inside `A`, `self` is that object, so you pass it to `foo`. Unclear what else you're looking for.

Comment: What I **think** you are asking is how to turn a function into a method, a process called *binding*. Python automatically [binds descriptor objects found on a class](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) when you access the named object on an instance of the class. That's how methods get bound and get `self` passed in, and properties are called when you access them.

Comment: If that's what you are trying to do, then know that that binding doesn't happen for instance attributes, but you can always do it manually: `self.f = func.__get__(self, type(self))`. Now `self.f` is a bound method, and calling `self.f()` will pass in the reference to the instance automatically.

Comment: Note that Python doesn't use the term 'member'. They are generally referred to as attributes, instead.

Comment: @deceze I have the question because `foo` is a function that has been used for a while in many scripts and I don't want to change its parameter list. Maybe I can change it to `def foo(bar=X)` so that I don't have to modify all scripts where it's used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done the right thing.

A function is just a function - it can't ordinarily guess if it was called from within a method instance, a function, or top-level code, and neither if it was hardcoded in the place from where it was called or if the caller have got it as a parameter. Through execution stack introspection, it is possible to find out these situations, but normally it is not desirable.

Just pass the instance as a parameter as you did:

```py
def callfunc(self):
  self.f(self)
```

Alternatively, you can make a passed-in function to an instance to work as if it were a method. Your code is still good, because it is very readable and obvious, but if you'd not want to have a "callfunc" method, and have the controller of an instance of `A` to be able to just call `instance.f()` just as is done with methods defined in the body of `class A`, you can, instead of binding the instance "f" itself, bind a "partial" object which have the instance parameter already filled in:

```py
from functools import partial
from random import randint

class A:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.f = partial(func, self)

    def odd(self):
        a = randint(1, 42)
        return a % 2

def foo(self):
    # Is there any place-holder here that refers to an object of A?
    # for example a place-holder named X
    if self.odd():
        # ...
    else:
        # ...

a = A(foo)
a.f()
```

And getting back to your question, not that there would be no problem - and also increase readability, just name the parameter referring to the instance `self`, as if it were an ordinary method. Note however that there is no special treatment from the language to the name "self". (Some tools and code editors, such as syntax highlighters might color it differently, though)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I didn't know `functools.partial`.